# Magento getting Order saving error: Disallowed file type. error when uploading image

Tags: magento-1.9

When I'm uploading an image through admin panel, I am getting below error:

> Order saving error: Disallowed file type.

Can anyone help me what can I do to solve this?

Comment: what file type you uploaded?

Comment: Hi Thank you for helping. I fixed the issue. There was a permission issue for the specific type of images.

Comment: @KNKM please post it as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's either due to the image size or the images pixels. Be sure to check if other images works as if they do you know the problem will be with the image you are trying to upload and not a permission error.